# Converting BNF to javacc code

Tags: javacc, ebnf

I need to convert the following to javacc from EBNF, I have tried various methods however I am getting an error.

EBNF: code ::== [\x20 - \x7E]

How would this be converted ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

JavaCC supports character ranges. E.g. `[" "-"~"]` It also supports Unicode escapes as in Java, e.g., `["\u0020"-"\u007E"]`.

These ranges can be used in the specification of the token manager.  Note that the three rules outlined in  [Question 3.3 of the FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm#tth_sEc3.3) apply.  So if you have

```
TOKEN: {
    <LETTER : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z"] >
|
    <PRINTABLE : [" "-"~"] >
}
```

then in the parser you will want

```
void Printable() {
    <LETTER> | <PRINTABLE>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So if I give the following as a grammar in javacc <PRINTABLE: [" " - "~"]>  it is the same as ["/u0020" -"/u007E"] ? Since wen i use the later i am geting s javacc compile error

Comment: Not quite. `< PRINTABLE : [" "-"~"] >` is the same as `< PRINTABLE : ["\u0020"-"\u007E"] >`.